# Raspberry Pi not picking up Wii controller or not communicating

Tags: raspberry-pi, wiimote, wii

I am trying to connect my Wii-mote's to my Raspberry Pi, so I can use them in pygame. I know to use the Wii controller, I need to make some configurations, and I have made them. However, when I run my .sh script to connect the remotes, I am thrown some errors. Here are the scripts:

/mywinput

```
#WiiMote
Wiimote.A  = BTN_A
Wiimote.B = BTN_B
Wiimote.Dpad.X = ABS_Y
Wiimote.Dpad.Y = -ABS_X
Wiimote.Minus = BTN_SELECT
Wiimote.Plus = BTN_START
Wiimote.Home = BTN_MODE
Wiimote.1 = BTN_X
Wiimote.2 = BTN_Y
# Nunchuk
Nunchuk.C = BTN_C
Nunchuk.Z = BTN_Z

Plugin.led.Led1 = 1
#Plugin.led.Led2 = 1
Plugin.led.Led3 = 1
#Plugin.led.Led4 = 1
```

/wiicontroller.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1 # Wait until Bluetooth services are fully initialized
hcitool dev | grep hci >/dev/null
if test $? -eq 0 ; then
    wminput -d -c  /home/pi/mywinput CC:FB:65:2C:52:8F &
else
    echo "Blue-tooth adapter not present!"
    exit 1

fi
```

I have made wiicontoller.sh executable:

```bash
sudo chmod 775 /home/pi/bin/connectwii.sh
```

Supposedly, I should press one and two one the controller and it should connect. However, the script returns immediately. And even then, when I press one and two, I get thrown errors. I don't think that should be possible as the script has returned, but here is the output:

```
Socket connect error (control channel)
```

I am also aware that using `cwiid` in python is another option. But that doesn't work either, as it does not detect my remote. wmgui also cannot pickup my remote. The only way I am able to detect my remote is through the `hcitool scan` command. Any help would be appreciated!